# partclone - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: raid, ext4, mdadm, partclone

I'm writing some backup scripts for my machines.  Up until now, I have enjoyed using partclone, but now I've hit a snag.

On this machine there's a large MDADM RAID which contains one EXT4 partition.  It is working.  I can mount it.  I can run fsck on it.  No problems.  But...

When I try partclone, it says it is computing a bitmap, spends about 2 minutes doing that, and reports completion, then is entirely silent.  Meanwhile, top(1) reports it is using 100% CPU time.  The output file is created but remains at 0 bytes.  After an overnight wait, this is still the case.  No progress.

Here's what lsblk says about the partition:

```
/root# lsblk -i -o +fstype /dev/md1
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE
md1       9:1    0 32.8T  0 raid5
`-md1p1 259:1    0 32.8T  0 part             ext4
```

When I mount the partition, here's what df(1) says about it:

```
/raidp# df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1p1       33T  7.2T   24T  24% /raidp
```

And when I unmount it and run fsck, here's what shows:

```
~# fsck.ext4 -f /dev/md1p1
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 65801045 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize<y>? no
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
new-raidp: 474652/1098637312 files (18.5% non-contiguous), 1996266631/8789097472 blocks
~#
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?  I really want to get my backups before I upgrade this system or do any further work.

Comment: I use Partclone only as part of Clonezilla, and doing so I run the computer booted from a 'Clonezilla USB pendrive'. If Partclone cannot manage your RAID system, and you still want a cloned copy or image, I suggest that you use something more basic (for example ddrescue), also when booted from another drive.